# Bar chart axis label font size and spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels

I have developed the pictured bar chart, however my axis labels are unreadable. How can I adjust the sizing to make it readable?

```
%matplotlib inline
#create labels strings
country_labels = iso_code_var[pop1mill][sorted_top_20_deaths]
#Mortalitiy for each country
mortalities_bar = total_deaths_mil_var[pop1mill][sorted_top_20_deaths]
#create a bar plot
dummy = plt.bar(np.arange(len(country_labels)),mortalities_bar,width=bar_width,tick_label=country_labels)
#assign name for x axis
plt.xlabel('iso_code')
#assign name for y axis
plt.ylabel('total_deaths_per_million')
#assign name for the bar chart
plt.title('Mortality for Countries with 1 million + Population')
#display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Would rotating the xticks vertically help you? `plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')`

Comment: That does thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the xticks vertically so that the labels don't overlap: `plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')`

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, so if it helped, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others with a similar question are directed to the answer, thanks!